# ionic2 - show ion-icon in alert controller title and buttons

Tags: angular, ionic2, modal-dialog, ionic3, ionicons

In ionic 2 application, is that possible to add **ion-icon** in the alert controller like shown below

```
    let showAlertCtrl = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: '<ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon>' +'Add your info',
  cssClass: 'myCustomCSS',
  message: msg,
  enableBackdropDismiss: false,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: '<ion-icon ios="iOS-search" md="md-add"></ion-icon>' +' Ok',
      cssClass: 'customAlertBtn',
      handler: (data: any) => {

      }
    },]
});

showAlertCtrl.present();
```

Need to display **ion-icon** image on both title and buttons. Is that possible?

Also I knew that we can use modal to achieve this. But my first priority to check it in alert controller.

Thanks
AK

Comment: As far as I know, Ionic doesn't support `ion-icons` in alerts. There is a feature request onto it: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7874

Answer (score 1):

A bit late response. I tried to achieve this today, and I made it like this:

Create a css class in your app.scss and add that class in the alert option "cssClass".

app.scss

```
.yourClass{
  background-image: url(your-image-url);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;  
}
```

These css values can be changed per your requirements.

And in the Alert:

```
buttons: [
           {
             text: '',
             cssClass: 'yourClass',
             handler: data => {}
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use a modal, you can make it look like an alert with css.For example:

```
    var z: any = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-modal");
    z[0].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
    z[0].style.padding = "36px";
    z[0].style.paddingTop = "150px";
    z[0].style.paddingBottom = "226px";
    z[0].childNodes[1].style.borderRadius = "6px";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use backticks to parse the html:

```
title: `<ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon>Add your info`
```

Comment: it is not working, I think we have to use modal only